# Cannot get PHP function to re-run and update array

Tags: php, arrays, curl

My PHP code looks something like this:

```
$size=1;
$newoffset=0;
$final=[];

function runQuery()
{
    global $newoffset;
    global $size;
    global $final;
    $SECRET_KEY = 'XXX';
    $s = hash_hmac('sha256','/api/v2/tags?limit=100&offset='.$newoffset.'-', $SECRET_KEY, false);
    $curl = curl_init();
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    $headers[] = "RT-ORG-APP-CLIENT-ID: XXX";
    $headers[] = "RT-ORG-APP-HMAC: ". $s;
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                  CURLOPT_URL => 'api/v2/tags?limit=100&offset='.$newoffset,
                  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
                  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
                ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        $array = json_decode( $response, true );
        $results = $array['data'];
        //print_r($results); This returns correctly
        $size = sizeof($array['data']); //size of array
        $result = array();

        if ($size>0){
            //print_r($results); This also returns correctly
            $newoffset += 100;
            foreach($results as $member) {
                $result[] = array(
                        'tag_name' => $member['name'],
                        'tag_id' => $member['id'],
                        'tag_public_id' => $member['public_id'],
                    );
            }
            $final['all_tags'] = $result;
        }
    }
}//end function

if($size>0){
    runQuery();
}else{
    echo json_encode($final);
}
```

What this is supposed to do is run the `curl` and if it returns results then push those results into `$final`. If there are results, then increase the value of a variable (`newoffset`) so that it can be used in the curl request. This is because I can only get 100 results at a time and need to do `offset` as many times as necessary to get them all.

If the size of what's returned is 0, then stop and echo the results.

However, this returns nothing.

I'm thinking I have a global variable problem.

Note that I know the query works if I remove all the conditionals and functions, so that isn't the issue.

Any suggestions on how to fix?

Comment: I'd recommend starting by formatting your code.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: @JonStirling Updated

Comment: @RiggsFolly Updated

Comment: Really? Does not look like it to me

Comment: @jonmrich ME either, you changed the indentation of one line.

Comment: @JonStirling Damn...didn't paste correctly. Thanks for fixing.

Comment: You can thank @RiggsFolly :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for the formatting...where's this extra `}` not seeing it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Removing that throws a 500 error "unexpected end of input"

Comment: Looking at the code, is returning nothing actually the success case?

Comment: @JonStirling No...I'm actually expecting this to run 5 or 6 times based on what I know is in the API

Comment: Run 5 or 6 times with no loop?

Comment: @JonStirling No..5 or 6 loops

Comment: Where do you think you are creating a loop? There is no loop

Comment: @RiggsFolly I meant "loop". I just want to do the if/then test as many times as necessary.

Comment: I'm confused by the options you are setting for the cURL request - you use `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET"` and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_json` ~ is that just a mistake??

Comment: @RamRaider Yes...bad copy and pasting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `runQuery` function is running only once because you're calling it only once. Execution does not continue at the line where the function declaration ends, it continues where the function was called, which in your case is the end of your script.

You'll have to move the

```
if($size>0){
    runQuery();
}else{
    echo json_encode($final);
}
```

part into the function and just call `runQuery` once.

Also, using global variables is discouraged because it could lead to clashes with other code. It's better to use function parameters and return values.

Comment: Thanks...this makes sense. If I do this, I only get the last run of the function though.

Comment: Actually this does not make a lot of sense

Comment: @RiggsFolly Do you haver any suggestions then?

Comment: Sorry, got to go to meeting.

Comment: It's returning only the last run because you are overwriting `$final['all_tags']` with every run. Substitute `$result[]` with `$final['all_tags'][]` in your foreach loop.

Comment: @BjörnTantau That's giving me an empty array

Comment: @BjörnTantau Wait...got it. Had to remove another line as well. Thanks!